# Написать программу, которая выводит количество повторяющихся цифр в числе. Java

Tags: java, циклы

Написать программу, которая считывает число и выводит количество всех содержащихся в нем цифр (от 0 до 9). Вывести соответствующий номер, только если он встречается хотя бы один раз.
Использовать «number% 10», чтобы получить последнюю цифру целого числа. «number / 10», чтобы отрезать последнюю цифру. Всё это без использования массивов с вложенным циклом.
Я много чего извратил, но ещё и проблема в том, что мне надо вывести только один раз.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    long number = sc.nextInt();
    long rest = 0;
    long number3 = number;

    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        int value = 0;
        long rest2 = 0;
        rest = number%10;
        long number2 = number3;
        for (int j = 0; j <= number2; j++) {
            rest2 = number2%10;
            if (rest == rest2){
                value++;
            }
            number2 = number2/10;
        }
        System.out.println(rest+" kommt "+ value + " mal vor.");
        number = number/10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаете массив для цифр и вперед

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    long number = scanner.nextInt();

    int[] digits = new int[10];

    while (number > 0) {
        digits[(int)(number%10)]++;
        number/=10;
    }

    for(int i=0; i< digits.length; i++){
        if (digits[i] > 0){
            System.out.println(i + " встречается " + digits[i] + " раз(а).");
        }
    }
```